# Where to call the reloadData when updating tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am very new to swift programming so probably asking you a basic question but something I need to know.

I have an implementation where I am chatting with a bot so to speak. So the control flow is this:

I say "hi" this has to be reflected in the "chat" box and then the response that comes back from the web service also has to become a chat message.

Obviously, my messages and the other response from the web service should be of different colours and styles and I am doing that in my tableView function.

Here is my tableView code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:tblCell = tblCell()
    let font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica" , size: 14)

    if(tableView.isEqual(messageTableView)) {
        var chatMessage:ChatMessage =  self.messageArray[indexPath.row]
        cell=self.messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as! tblCell
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //Determining the size of the chat box
            cell.messageText.sizeToFit()
            cell.messageText.text = chatMessage.message
            cell.messageText.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.messageText.font = font
            var frame: CGRect = cell.messageText.frame
            cell.messageText.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.messageText.layer.masksToBounds = true

            //if it is a user input message use this
            if(chatMessage.messageType == "user") {
                cell.messageText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
                cell.messageText.backgroundColor = self.UIColorFromRGB(0x0099FF)
                cell.messageText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

                //code to right align the label
                if(frame.width <= 148) {
                    frame.origin.x = 148 - frame.width
                }
                else {
                    frame.origin.x = 0
                }
                cell.messageText.frame = frame

            } else if(chatMessage.messageType == “bot”) {
                cell.messageText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
                cell.messageText.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            }
            var size:CGSize = CGSize(width: frame.width + 20, height: frame.height + 20)
            cell.messageText.sizeThatFits(size)

            if tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height  && self.shouldScrollToLastRow {
                let offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height)
                tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
                self.shouldScrollToLastRow = false
            }
        }
        return cell
    }        
    return cell
}
```

Now I am experiencing trouble with the size of the message as it doesn't return the right size all the time. Meaning, as I scroll up and down, the size of the boxes keep changing.

I am thinking the problem is with reloadData() and I am not sure where I should be calling it.

Please note that I have an asynchronous request parse code written down and updating my chat from the response of the request.

What am I doing wrong?

Please help

Nikhil

Comment: Also, the right label sizes are only visible when i start scrolling. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you properly implemented all of the tableview configuration methods in your delegate and datasource? [Delegate docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) Particularly heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Yes I have Will. I have all the methods implemented. I had to configure the cell height and label height based on response and that has also been done.